# How to find an HTMLElement from the component.ts, not having any reference to it in the component.html?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

In my Angular app in my **component.html** I have a game board displayed by iteration of `i` and `j`:

```
<div class="board text-center">
        <div
          class="boardRow"
          *ngFor="
            let row of this.boards[this.clientsPlayerNumber];
            let i = index
          "
        >
          <div *ngFor="let box of row; let j = index">
            <div
              class="boardCell"
              [style.backgroundColor]="box.color"
              #cell
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Is there a chance to get in my **component.ts** any `HTMLElement` of this board cell, when not having interaction (events) in the view, but having only `i` and `j` in the **component.ts**?

Later on I want to use it to display animation having `HTMLElement`:

```
...
this.animateSprite(true, someViewElementHavingIandJ);
...

private animateSprite(isHit: boolean, ref: HTMLElement): void {
    this.displaySprite = true;
    this.spriteX = ref.offsetLeft - 50;
    this.spriteY = ref.offsetTop - 50;
    this.spriteUrl = isHit
      ? 'https://i.ibb.co/H4f84Wn/explode.png'
      : 'https://i.ibb.co/c3WLWN1/splash.png';
  }
```

Can I combine somehow `#cell` with `i` and `j` in the view, to use it later on as a `@ViewChild('cell-i-j', { static: true }) cell-i-j: ElementRef;`?

Comment: create a component for your cell with x and y as inputs. Use then `ViewChildren(CellCompoentn)` in host-component to select the instances of Cell-Components

Comment: Here another solution based on a directive:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233844/angular2-querylist-based-on-element-class

Comment: Regarding the first solution, how can I get then `HTMLElement` of the component i need?

Comment: Within the CellComponent you need to select the HTMLElement via ref (#cell; @ViewChild('cell') cellNode; ) Then you can do `this.cellNode.nativeElement`

Comment: Here as example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kxs4wc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It looks promissing with `ref: ElementRef;`, Ill have time to try it later on, and Ill come to you with this. Thank you